# Tool that calculates total drag for a submarine

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Can you please suggest a tool (software or online tool) that can analyze a submarine hull shape and give the total drag at a specific velocity.

A simplified tool would work too, where I select a general geometry, then input the dimensions and speed, and get the drag force.

I'm reading Submarine Hydrodynamics by Martin Renilson, where he writes "For a typical submarine the total submerged pressure resistance does not exceed 10–20% of the skin friction resistance. Thus, the skin friction dominates the resistance of a deeply submerged submarine."

I'm assuming that this is the case for slow speed only, and that pressure resistance is the dominating resistance at high speed, or submarine hulls wouldn't be so streamlined. Or am I wrong?

My application is for low speed, and I need a non conventional hull shape that is flat (box shaped), and I'm trying to understand how much penalty I will have to pay for this.

The standard drag equation is too simplified in my case, because it approximates both skin drag and pressure drag into one variable (the drag coefficient).

Comment: The drag force equation $F=\rho V^2 L^2 C_d$ is not a simplification, it is a fully correct equation where all details of viscous vs. inertial forces are in the function $C_d(Re)$ where $C_d$ is a function of the geometric shape and the Reynolds number. For some shapes, for some range of Re, the coefficients $C_d$ are tabulated, e.g., in the article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_coefficient, it looks like some cubic shapes are included there.

Comment: @MaximUmansky: I'm a beginner at this, so maybe I've misunderstood the drag equation. So the drag coefficient is dependent on the Reynolds number. But isn't the Reynolds number dependent on the physical size of the object, not just its geometry, and isn't it also dependent on the fluid velocity? I have the sense that the drag coefficient is only useful for a range of velocities and a range of sizes. Or?

Comment: The drag force depends on the body geometry (size and shape), its velocity, and the fluid characteristics, density and viscosity. There is nothing else there, if the fluid model is Navier-Stokes equation. So the drag force equation $=\rho ^2 ^2 _$ is just a dimensionally correct form where all details are hidden in $C_d$. That function $C_d$ depends on all those things -  the body size and shape, velocity, fluid density and viscosity. But the powerful statement from the hydro theory is that $C_d$ depends on those things in a specific way, because $\rho,V,L,\mu$ are lumped together.

Comment: Thanks Maxim. The drag equation makes it look as if Cd is a constant. Just look up the Cd for your shape, and then use the drag equation to calculate the drag force at various velocities. But in reality this is not how it works, because Cd varies with velocity. To use the drag equation for a specific velocity, I first have to calculate the Cd for that velocity. Is this correct? If yes, then how is the drag equation simplifying anything?

Comment: It simplifies everything because the drag would have to be calculated from a velocity and pressure profile integrated on the surface of the object using CFD or measured experimentally. Using the drag coefficient saves you the trouble for that.

Comment: If it’s worth anything there are people who have built careers out of exploring this sort of thing.

Comment: If $C_d$ is a slow function of the Reynolds number in some range of it then you can take it as constant indeed. The function $C_d(Re)$ has been tabulated for many shapes. The main benefit of writing the drag force in terms of $C_d$ is it allows exploiting hydrodynamic similarity which is the basis of wind tunnels, the main tool there before computers. So you can do a wind tunnel experiment (or computer simulation) for one sphere (cube, cylinder etc.) and that would give you the answer for all similar shapes.

Comment: The key piece in @MaximUmansky's answers is that $C_d$ is often "more or less constant" within a reasonable range of velocities.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, now it makes sense to me! Interesting subject.

Comment: Thinking further about this, I believe the pressure drag is the integral of forces normal to the body surface, and the skin drag is the integral of forces tangential to the surface. So, if the body is streamlined then the side surface area is large but the frontal cross-section is small, so that's why skin friction dominates. But I would not agree that at higher velocity the pressure drag would dominate over the skin friction. Both skin drag and pressure drag coefficients are more or less constant for a range of large Re, so both forces would scale quadratically with the body velocity.

Comment: @BjörnMorén here us a link to the tutorial FE code to calculate drag for incompressible steady-state flow. You can put any shape you like. http://mofem.eng.gla.ac.uk/mofem/html/tutorial_navier_stokes.html

Comment: @MaximUmansky Thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: @likask Thanks, will have a look at it.